# IE11 - Developer Tools Network Tab freezes IE

Tags: internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

I upgraded IE on my machine and found the upgraded developer tools better. However whenever I select the Network tab, IE hangs or freezes. I can do nothing on it.

Is there some setting that I might be missing to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My work around is to start IE with just a blank new tab.  I turn on Network and then navigate to wherever I need to do my work.  So far I've been lock up free when doing this.

Answer (score 7):

There is an entry in Microsoft Connect database for that. Unfortunately, there is no fix for now...

http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/801628/ie11-developer-tools-network-tab-causes-freeze

Comment: Its a religion in MS to serve half-cooked meals!

Comment: Sadly, it's true what you say @Kangkan, but on a happier note, one of the workarounds did the trick for me, so the link is highly recommended

Comment: Would have been nice to document a useful workaround here, because now the link is dead.